# how can I know what's drivers I need to install?

Tags: drivers

How can I know what is drivers are need to install for my hardware, and how can I check that all drivers work, especially the Vga driver.

I know that can go to additional drivers window can see the drivers but if I in tty can't do that or if I in any another distro or dde can't do that too

so is there any command to do that to check if I need or don't need to install another drivers and to check if all drivers working good or not???

Comment: Try `System Testing` it is already installed in Ubuntu..

Comment: thx man I will use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -e ":" -e driver
```

It will show you what drivers are in use.

As for making sure all drivers work as expected, just use the computer.

Comment: thx man  for this command it's very useful (y)